# How come my async await doesn't wait my web3.js sendRawTransaction?

Tags: node.js, async-await, web3js

I have an async function which I call. The function has an await for my web3.js `sendRawTransaction`. I have a `console.log` after it to test if it indeed waits. But it immediately prints before web3 is done sending the transaction. I'm suspecting that `sendRawTransaction` isn't a promise, and therefore can't be called via await.

Here is the function

```
async function sendImage() {
var count = web3.eth.getTransactionCount(Wallet1);

var rawTransaction = {
    "from": Wallet1,
    "nonce": web3.toHex(count),
    "gasPrice": "0x2540BE400",
    "gasLimit": "0x3A980",
    "to": imageContract,
    "value": "0x0",      
    "data": imageContractABI.startGame.getData(2, {from: Wallet1}),
    "chainId": 0x04
};


var privKey = new Buffer (PrivKey1, 'hex');
var tx = new Tx(rawTransaction);


tx.sign(privKey);
var serializedTx = tx.serialize();


await web3.eth.sendRawTransaction('0x' + serializedTx.toString('hex'), function(err, hash) {
    if (!err){
      console.log("Image is sent " + hash);
    }
    else
        console.log(err);

}); 

console.log("after aync await..");

}
```

I want to see "after async await.." printed after the web3 has gone, and before I see "image is sent". But, I get the reverse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im not sure, but you use async/await and callback in same operation. Try to refactor like this:

```
const hash = await web3.eth.sendRawTransaction('0x' + serializedTx.toString('hex'))
console.log(hash)
conosle.log("after aync await..")
```

Comment: Yes, that works quite well. The only problem is trying to getTransactionReceipt(hash) afterwards now that I have the hash. It will think it is done with await and always return `null`

Comment: which provider do you use? infura or your own ethereum node?

Comment: Using Infura Rinkeby

Comment: hm infura works fine to me for pending transactions (aprox 1-2% requests return null, but others return tx's receipt)

Comment: Okay, well essentially all I'm trying to do is wait for the transaction to actually go through before proceeding with the rest of my steps. I just want the transaction to actually be finallized on the blockchain before I call other web3 functions.